# Including a javascript file inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, .net

I have a need to include a javascript file inside another javascript function. I dont have any html file. I am executing the javascript code inside a .NET program like this

```
                MSScriptControl.ScriptControl js = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
                js.AllowUI = false;
                js.Language = "JScript";
                js.Reset();
                js.AddCode(@"
                function test(x)
                {
                  return x+10;
                }
                ");
```

I need to reference a javascript file inside the function test. Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: whats the goal? do you need some code from another .js file?

Comment: @alexanderb yes,exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such instruction like 'include' in javascript language. So, to accomplish what you want you have to read another script content and concatinate it with the rest of code;

The code would be something like that:

```
var includedScript = ReadScriptFromFile("myfile.js");
var includedScript += @"function (x) { return x + 10";

js.AddCode(includedScript);
```

Comment: but,what is ReadScriptFromFile? I am writing this code in ASP.net codebehind file

Comment: this is the function that you have to write by yourself; read the content of file and returns it, that is easy